# Escaping non special characters in string for LDAP query

Tags: c#, string, escaping, ldap

I hope that I have titled this question appropriately. Bit of a mixed subject here.

I have created a function in `C#` that creates an Active Directory User. Using an LDAP string that needs to look like this:

```
userinfo.displayName = "Surname, Firstname"

CN=" + userinfo.displayName, "user"
```

The following exception message is passed back, because of the comma being in the string.

> An invalid dn syntax has been specified.

The full dn after the string has been applied is as following

```
"CN=Surname**,** Lastname,OU=Users,DC="Foo",DC="net"
```

The comma in the common name CN= is the problem...

Is there a way  that C# can ignore the comma out of the string? Effectively escaping it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Escape invalid characters in a distinguished name is done with a leading slash ('\'). For example, the distinguished name above should be:

```
"CN=Surname\, Lastname,OU=Users,DC=Foo,DC=net"
```

According to section 2.4 of [RFC 4514: Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP): String Representation of Distinguished Names](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4514.txt), the characters , `"`, `#`, `+`, `,`, `;`, `<`, `=`, `>`, and `\` can be escaped by a leading slash. Other non-alphanumeric characters should be shown in the form of `\XX` where XX are the hex digits of the UTF8 character encoding. See section 4 for examples.

Note that the [X500DistinguishedName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x01h8y30.aspx) class (in System.Security Cryptography) does not appear to have a Parse or Escape method to help in this situation.

Answer (score 6):

Certain characters **must** be escaped with a backslash (`\`) **followed by two hex digits**, not a single backslash according to RFC4514. Many directory directory server support the `\,`, but since it is not standardized, LDAP clients must not use this notation - it would work on some servers but not others and clients must not assume they are communicating with a particular servers' software.