# Using CertReq.exe, how to encode special characters in Subject

Tags: windows, sdk, distinguishedname

We are using Microsoft Certificate Request (CertReq.exe) to build certificate requests programmatically. For this purpose, we have to create input INF files, [see docs here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn296456.aspx).

The Subject property is defined as `Relative Distinguished Name string values`, which should be encoded like specified by [RFC 1779](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1779.txt).

That essentially means to simply escape some characters (`"`, `+`, `,`, `;`, `<`, `>`, or `\`) by prefixing it with `\`.

The problem is, that I could not figure out, how to properly encode a Subject that has the property "O=Foo + Bar".

Input (relevant INF part):

```
[NewRequest]
Subject = "CN=www.foo.de,OU=Foobar,O=Foo \+ Bar,L=Foo,S=Bar,C=DE"
```

Output:

```
The string contains an invalid X500 name attribute key, oid, value or delimiter. 0x80092023 (-2146885597 CRYPT_E_INVALID_X500_STRING)
c:\file_path.inf([NewRequest] Subject = "CN=www.foo.de,OU=Foobar,O=Foo \+ Bar,L=Foo,S=Bar,C=DE")
```

Duplicate escaping (using `"`and `\`) is discouraged by RFC 1799, but seems to solve problems in LDAP queries ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550358/escaping-non-special-characters-in-string-for-ldap-query), f.i.).
However, we also tried do not use the quotation to specify a subject, but got another unwanted result.

Input:

```
[NewRequest]
Subject = CN=www.foo.de,OU=Foobar,O=Foo \+ Bar,L=Foo,S=Bar,C=DE
```

Output:

```
The data is invalid. 0x8007000d (WIN32: 13 ERROR_INVALID_DATA)
c:\file_path.inf([NewRequest] Subject = "CN=www.foo.de", "OU=Foobar", "O=Foo \+ Bar", "L=Foo", "S=Bar", "C=DE")
```

The whole process works without the `+` sign. What is the correct way to encode a RDN (relative distinguished name) in the INF file?

Comment: Related; where there's a comma in the DN: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/fa15d9ef-bd36-4fdd-86fc-9fa83417fc4c/how-to-insert-special-characters-in-dn?forum=winserversecurity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the `+` character has special meaning. You can disable that behavior like this and just use the `+` character like you would any other.

```
Subject = CN=www.foo.de,OU=Foobar,O=Foo + Bar,L=Foo,S=Bar,C=DE
X500NameFlags = 0x20000000
```

The plus character is normally reserved to separate multiple values for multi-valued RDNs.

I'm not entirely sure why escaping it does not work with CertEnroll as you are expecting it to.

Comment: That did it! There are other encoding issues, f.i. UTF-8 chars, escaping quotes, etc. but I'll start another question after experimenting with other X500NameFlags.

Comment: For documentation on X500NameFlags see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379394%28v=vs.85%29.aspx